# Auto-launch app when iphone docked to dock station?

Tags: iphone

i need to launch an app automatically when iphone is docked to dock station..is there anyway to do this...

Comment: Not sure about the 2 close votes here. It's a valid question; it's just not possible.

Comment: I'm guessing the close votes are because this is a site about writing code, and the question is asking how to use an iPhone. Maybe http://superuser.com/ would be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot automatically launch an application on the iPhone when the dock connector is connected to the device.

Comment: So the API doesn't allow this?